# How to made php code to generate this json?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

This is the result of mysql query

```
` date      |    link                               |sum
2015-06-29  |uploads/1_29_06_2015_9_18_37_image.jpg |6
2015-06-29  |uploads/1_29_06_2015_13_57_54_image.jpg|2
2015-06-30  |uploads/1_30_06_2015_0_26_44_image.jpg |2
2015-07-01  |uploads/1_01_07_2015_2_44_47_image.jpg |3
2015-07-01  |uploads/1_01_07_2015_5_15_47_image.jpg |4
2015-07-02  |uploads/1_02_07_2015_1_40_05_image.jpg |2`
```

Can someone please help me generate a json with the format below through PHP.

```
[
{ 
"date": "2015-06-29",
"values": [{"image":"uploads/1_29_06_2015_9_18_37_image.jpg","sum":6},{"image":"uploads/1_29_06_2015_13_57_54_image.jpg","sum":2}]
},
{ 
"date": "2015-06-30 ",
"values": [{"link":"uploads/1_30_06_2015_0_26_44_image.jpg","sum":2}]
}
]
```

I want to group the link and sum together when they are on the same day.

UPDATE 1:
This is my code :

```
<?php


$uid = $_SESSION['uid']; 

  $registerquery = mysql_query("select DATE(date) as dates,pic, sum(veg)+sum(fruit) as sum from diary where u_id = $uid and  pic !='' group by date;");




$data = array();
foreach (mysql_fetch_row($registerquery) as $row) {
  if (!array_key_exists($row['dates'], $data)) {
    $data[$row['dates']] = array('date' => $row['dates'], 'values' => array());
  }

  $data[$row['dates']]['values'][] = array(
    'image' => $row['pic'],
    'sum' => $row['sum']      
  ); 
}

//this is your JSON
echo json_encode(array_values($data));

?>
```

But I only seem to get the first char.

```
[{"date":"2","values":[{"image":"0","sum":"1"}]},{"date":"u","values":[{"image":"p","sum":"l"}]},{"date":"6","values":[{"image":"","sum":""}]}]
```

Comment: Have you coded something yet? You will get a lot more answers of your questions asks for a fix in a code, than asking someone to code the entire thing.

Comment: I tried the code .. i am having a few errors  ... i am triyng to check if it is something I did wrong give me 5 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `$rows` contains all fetched rows:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  if (!array_key_exists($row['DATE'], $data)) {
    $data[$row['DATE']] = array('date' => $row['DATE'], 'values' => array());
  }

  $data[$row['DATE']]['values'][] = array(
    'image' => $row['LINK'],
    'sum' => $row['SUM']      
  ); 
}

//this is your JSON
echo json_encode(array_values($data));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jedrzej. I tried it out. But I think I did something wrong. Could you please check the UPDATE i made and point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include "connect.php"; ?>

<?php


$uid = $_SESSION['uid']; 

  $registerquery = mysql_query("select DATE(date) as dates,pic, sum(veg)+sum(fruit) as sum from diary where u_id = $uid and  pic !='' group by date;");




$data = array();
while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($registerquery)) {

//    echo $row['dates']; echo "   "; echo $row['pic'];  echo "  ";  echo $row['sum']; echo "<br><br>";

    if (!array_key_exists($row['dates'], $data)) {
    $data[$row['dates']] = array('date' => $row['dates'], 'values' => array());
  }

    $data[$row['dates']]['values'][] = array(
    'image' => $row['pic'],
    'sum' => $row['sum']      
  ); 

}

echo json_encode(array_values($data));



?>
```

Comment: the if statement was missin a closing bracket [in the code you provided]  and i used while loop and mysql_fetch_array .. initianlly i used mysql_fetch_row

Comment: i used XMLHttpRequest(); and got the json into an var obj.
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(food.responseText);
I cant seem to get the value from them i tried different ways  i tried console log(obj) i get ==  Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] ...